# window.scrollY in computed property is 0 on page reload, works fine with hot reload

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
<div id="component-navbar" :class="hasBackground">
```

```
computed: {
  hasBackground() {
    if (window.scrollY > 0) {
      return 'has-background'
    }
  }
}
```

I have a sticky nav bar and I want to add a background if the page scroll is greater than 0. The problem is, `hasBackground`

1. doesn't get recalculated as the scroll changes
2. on page refresh `window.scrollY` is always zero, even though the page is scrolled
3. works only with hot reload when I make a change to a file.

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried using `window.pageYOffset`?

Comment: Yes, didn't help

Comment: I don't know what vue.js can do, but if you'll accept a purely javascript answer I'll get it for you. Basically you can work with a onscroll / onload event, call a function that pops up your background, or introduces the class you need when scrollY is > 0.

Comment: I would rather like to know if there is an elegant solution with vuejs, otherwise I can code it with an event handler.

Comment: The computed properties probably aren't going to help you here. Vue works with a lot of observer hooks, and `window` is not an object that it has said hooks for. To get it to recompute, you're almost definitely going to need to use scroll events, unless there's something I'm unaware of.

Comment: I'd also bet that the scroll property is always zero because the browser initializes it to zero on page load and then modifies it when it realizes you were scrolled down before, and since the computed property won't update as window is not being observed by vue, it won't update when that change happens after it's been initialized.

Comment: This turned out to be the issue - window isn't an observed property. If you type that as an answer I'll accept it. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `window` object cannot be observed properly in vue. You can learn more about vue's reactivity here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

I thought that it might be possible to proxy the `window` object in vue data, but I believe this actually creates a new object with getters/setters for existing property names, meaning that the new data you create by doing this would not be reactive to changes to the original `window` object, so the only real option is to watch for events unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah I tried a bunch of tricks with "watch" but nothing worked, good old events are the way to go! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As @obermillerk said:

> The `window` object cannot be observed properly in vue.

So you have 2 options:

1. Read `window.scrollY` when your component is initialized.
2. Add `window.addEventListener('scroll', ..., { passive: true })`.

### Read `window.scrollY` when your component is initialized

```js
Vue.component('component-navbar', {
  computed: {
    hasBackground () {
      console.log('window.scrollY', window.scrollY)
      if (window.scrollY > 0) {
        return 'has-background'
      }
    }
  },
  template: '<nav :class="hasBackground"></nav>'
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```css
#app {
  min-height: 110vh;
}
nav {
  min-height: 50vh;
}
nav.has-background {
  background: linear-gradient(red, orange);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<article id="app">
  <component-navbar></component-navbar>
</article>
```

### Add `window.addEventListener('scroll', ..., { passive: true })`

```js
Vue.component('component-navbar', {
  data () {
    return {
      isScrolled: false
    }
  },

  computed: {
    hasBackground () {
      if (this.isScrolled) {
        return 'has-background'
      }
    }
  },

  template: '<nav :class="hasBackground"></nav>',

  mounted () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.setIsScrolled, { passive: true })
    this.setIsScrolled()
  },

  destroyed () {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.setIsScrolled, { passive: true })
  },

  methods: {
    setIsScrolled () {
      this.isScrolled = window.scrollY > 0
    }
  },
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```css
#app {
  min-height: 110vh;
}
nav {
  min-height: 50vh;
}
nav.has-background {
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, orange);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<article id="app">
  <component-navbar></component-navbar>
</article>
```